# Export google search console data to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-search-console

I am trying to export all my google search console(gsc) data to Bigquery(BQ) using this doc link:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12917675

I already have a account say account-1@gmail.com where all my other BQ data lies. Now want to export all by gsc data from account-2@gmail.com to account-1@gmail.com.

For that I added full owner access IAM permission for both 'account-2@gmail.com' and 'search-console-data-export@system.gserviceaccount.com' in 'account-1@gmail.com'. Still I am getting 'Unknown Error' at time of export.

[image]

Comment: Try doing it a couple of times. When I did it, it worked on the third attempt.

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you using account-1 to set up the export to a project in BigQuery? And are then giving account-2 access to that project? Does that BigQuery project have another GSC exporting to it?

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown error` is an export failed for unknown reasons. You can just wait for another export and see if the same error will exist. It seems that you do not have any problems with your setup since you granted your account an `Owner` IAM permission role.

While you are having an export error, you can manage and monitor your bulk data exports [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12919198#zippy=%2Cstart-a-bulk-data-export). There are also details about the errors and fixes inside the link.

Note: ExportLog in BigQuery is not logging the export errors of Search Console.